# Publish enum members as spring beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have a preexisting enum.

```
enum Foo {
  FOO1,
  FOO2,
  ...
}
```

I now want to publish all members as spring beans. I could do:

```
@Bean("FOO1")
public Foo foo1(){
   return Foo.FOO1;
}


@Bean("FOO2")
public Foo foo2(){
   return Foo.FOO2;
}

...
```

And so on. Is there a way publish all enum members at once?

Commenters asked ***why*** I want to do this:

There is another component `BarService` with

```
 @Autowired
 List<Bar> allTheBars;
```

It collects plenty of Bars already.

I need to make all members of enum `Foo` available to `BarService`, too. It would be easiest to have them implement `Bar` and turn them into beans. Alternatively I could add them manually within `BarService` but that requires me to change `BarService`.

Comment: I see little to no benefits in making an enum also a Spring Bean. Could you elaborate on the `why` part?

Comment: So instead of writing `List<Bar> allTheBars = Arrays.asList(Foo.values())` you want to write a config class and make beans out of enums... I would strongly suggest to make the oneliner change instead of abusing dependency injection for this.

Comment: No. There are plenty of other bars already. I have to add all the foos.

Comment: `I need to make all members of enum Foo available to BarService, too`. Public enum  class values ARE ALREADY available to any class, you just don't need to 'beanify' them, it looks like overkill

Answer (score 2):

There is always only one instance per enum value in a single JVM instance. You could just use `Foo.FOO1` wherever you need it in the code without having to inject it as a bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `Enum`  in one of configuration something like:

```
@Bean(name="EnumBeans")
    Foo[] enums() {
        return Foo.values();
}
```

Now, this will give you all values / members as soon as you access them:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="EnumBeans")
    Foo[] enums;
    ..
    public void accessor(){
    for(Foo e:enums) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
   }
```